# Windows Authentication for Specific windows user group

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

I created asp.net webpage , i want to log on my asp page using windows username and password when login button click. i have search some code(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37558/Windows-Authentication-Using-Form-Authentication) in net for login my asp page. It works for my local user name and password but i want to access Specific domain group members to my asp.net page

Someone help me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To provide/restrict access to specific users/groups, appropriate entries needs to be done in `Web.config`.

In Windows authentication names are entered in the format `DomainName\UserName` or `ComputerName\UserName`.

You need to use the same format when listing users in the authorization rules. For example, if you have the user accounts john and nolan on a computer named FARIAMAT, you can use these authorization rules. Note the `users` attribute in `<allow>` element.

```
<authorization> 
<deny users="?" /> 
<!-- permit only specific users to have access -->
<allow users="FARIAMAT\john,FARIAMAT\nolan" /> 
<deny users="*" /> 
</authorization>
```

To permit all users of an NT Group named Managers to have access to your resources, use the following code. Note the `roles` attribute in `<allow>` element.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
  <!-- Format is:: <allow roles="DomainName\WindowsGroup" /> -->
      <allow roles="domainname\Managers" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**NOTE::**
Windows groups are used as roles and they take the form `domainName\windowsGroup`. Groups such as `Administrators` are referenced by using the `BUILTIN` prefix as:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="DomainName\john, DomainName\nolan" />
  <allow roles="BUILTIN\Administrators, DomainName\Manager" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```