# WebClient Authentication on Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, authentication, iis

We have a Console App (C#) and Web Server (IIS). The Console App needs to send a file via HTTPS POST to the Web Server. Now, we need to add authentication between the Console App and Web Server, and we're trying to use WebClient's Credentials system.

The Console App's upload code:

```
            WebClient uploadWebClient = new WebClient();
            uploadWebClient.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(UploadFileCallback);

            // Authentication
            uploadWebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            uploadWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usernameString, passwordString);

            // Upload via HTTPS POST
            uploadWebClient.UploadFileAsync(new Uri(destURI), "POST", "file.ext");
```

The server sided code is:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach(string f in Request.Files.AllKeys) {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[f];
        file.SaveAs("Z:\\" + file.fileName);
    }
}
```

How do we implement the use of credentials on the server side?

Comment: Which Authentication "System" do you use on Server Side? IIS Authentication/Own custom authentication?

Comment: @STORM we don't have any at the moment, I think. We just need anything that would simply work with the Console App's code. Would IIS Authentication work in this case?

Comment: Are you within an Intranet or Extranet/Internet?

Comment: @STORM Intranet, with AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example Windows Authentication in IIS to secure the WebSite. Then you can have your users within AD and if you try to access the page you will receive an error if user is not allowed.

If you need to check single users, then you need to store somewhere (maybe SQL, Oracle, MySQL or any other DB) the users in a DB table and then you have to grab the calling windows users login information and then check if he/she is able to able to access your solution by looking into the db table.

Of course you can just manage the users in IIS if you dont need to define Roles, etc. See also this post: **https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-using-windows-authentication-with-minimal-permissions-granted-to-disk** (i thing this one is what you are looking for!) or [Windows Authentication for Specific windows user group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991983/windows-authentication-for-specific-windows-user-group) or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Due to missing details it is not possible to give you a specific answer, but thats the way you can do it. One is Windows Authentication is IIS within maybe user management in web.config or IIS itself or the other solution is to get the calling user on the backend and check against you custom db.