# Forms Authentication and infinite redirects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis-7, .net-4.5

We have several HTML pages under virtual directory *Payroll* in `IIS7`. One of the html pages is called *Sales.html*. All these pages are pure HTML.

I've enabled `Forms Authentication` and modified `web.config` so that the HTML pages fall under this type of authentication. This is what my `web.config` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Users" value="BobJ,JosephB"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG"   type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
      <add name="HTM" path="*.htm" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="appNameAuth" path="/" loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.html" protection="All" timeout="525600">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="[user]" password="[password]" />
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
        <add extension=".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So `Page_Load` of `login.aspx` looks like this. With *Forms Authentication*, anyone visiting any *Sales.html* will be redirected to `login.aspx`. 
What I wanted to do was to check, in `page_load`, compare the user with a list of users in web.config, and `Response.Redirect` according to the user:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string htmlPage = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    string user = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;

    string users = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Users"].ToString();

    string[] allUsers = users.Split(',');

    if (allUsers.ToList().Contains(user))
    {
        Response.Redirect(htmlPage);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("InvalidUser.html");
    }

}
```

The issue is the infinite redirect: every time `page_load` redirects to *Sales.html*, it will take me to *login.aspx*, which will then take me *again *to *Sales.html*. It's a never-ending loop.

What alternatives do I have? I don't want to create a landing page.

Comment: Just a possible suggestion would be to modify `Sales.html` to check for some kind of query string parameter that you pass along when the user is included in the config list, and if that parameter is sent, allow access without the redirect to login.

Comment: But I would need to add serverside code to all html pages.

Comment: From the way you explained it, it sounded like you only had to worry about this on redirect to `Sales.html` but I imagine you could do some kind of inheritance and have all your pages inherit from that so that you could only add the redirect logic once.

Comment: All the html pages are pure html. I didn't do any inheritance because that would mean I have to add server-side code to all html pages.

Comment: Couldn't you just put exceptions inside your web.config file like outlined in this article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628445/allow-access-for-unathenticated-users-to-specific-page-using-asp-net-forms-authe) and this (https://forums.asp.net/t/2105905.aspx?deny+user+and+allow+user+in+web+config+file) ?? Then you can just grant access to the specific users in the config.

Comment: `So Page_Load looks like this.` Page_Load of which page?

Comment: page_load of login.aspx. It's the only page with serverside code.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but are you setting the authentication cookie? I would think it's redirecting because it's missing the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the solution in [Windows Authentication for Specific windows user group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991983/windows-authentication-for-specific-windows-user-group) and added `<authorization>` inside `<system.web>`:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="domain\bobj, domain\ralphk" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

My web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
      <add name="HTM" path="*.htm" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="domain\bobj, domain\ralphk" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
        <add extension=".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```